# I need to code an anonymous 'voting' function that I am finding quite complex. Could anyone point me in the right direction to get this correct?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Using Flutter, Android Studio and Firebase

Basic premise of app - Users create cards which contain an idea or event etc. with a big 'vote' button next to it, these are then displayed in a ListView on the main screen. The users invite people relevant to the idea and they can all click to vote. They are all notified the idea is going ahead ONLY when they all click the vote button.

Currently, the user's data and the data associated with the cards are stored in separate collections in Firebase and called upon when needed.

I still need to sort out the access so that only users and their invitees can see the cards they create, but I wanted to get the final part sorted before I did so I could set it up correctly.

Currently, my thought is that it could work with an IF-ELSE that works like:

```
IF - 'Number of users that have clicked vote' == 'Total users invited + currentUser' THEN push notification to let users know AND confetti animation.

Else - Do nothing.
```

The bits I'm unsure of are:

1. How to code the security and access to ensure only the current User and their invitees can see the event in their ListView main screen.
2. How to then code the IF - ELSE statement.

I know I'm asking a lot, and I'm not asking anyone to code it for me, but if someone could point me in the right direction, that would really help. I learn better from videos, as I'm a 'watch/listen, then practice' learner. Reading doesn't work for me when it comes to learning new concepts, despite being an avid reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't really intended for broad questions like these, and has policies against such, which is probably why your question has gotten some negative votes.

That said, here are a few resources you may find helpful that I found after only a couple minutes of Googling the specific topics you mentioned:

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started could get you started on the Firebase Security (there's a nice video on the page).
2. For the "If-Else" logic you refer to, the easiest way to do this would be using Firebase Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions (This page has a video introduction that may give you some ideas). Essentially you'll create a function that gets called when your database gets updated with a new vote, and then check the number of users in your database. If the number matches, you'll send the notification (see #3 below).
3. Since you are using Firebase, you'll probably send a notification to all users using Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging (this page also has a video with an introduction)
4. https://pub.dev/packages/confetti is a great package for the confetti effect :)

Of course there aren't any videos out there that explain specifically how to code the app you are trying to create. Free generative AI tools like ChatGPT can be helpful. These aren't allowed for producing answers on Stack Overflow, but after writing the answer above, I pasted your question into ChatGPT and found that it gave similar advice (although without links to videos), with the addition of some code examples for security rules.

Comment: Thank you for all this, I didn't realise there was a rule against broad questioning. That's good to know for the future.